# ActiveMQ vs Apollo vs RabbitMQ vs Qpid (AMQP)

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic, message-queue, qpid, apollo

I am trying to figure out the best MQ option for my requirements. I need to have the ability to transfer both text and binary messages within and across geographically diverse data centers with high reliability. Fast is nice but scaling is an option as well. Support is nice to have as with RabbitMQ.

Here are some assumptions:

1. Use federation or shoveling messages to push identical messages across data centers.
2. Use AMQP to transfer binary messages and since we are a .Net/Python shop.

I want to make sure my assumptions are valid and need help with which MQ to pick. I have used ActiveMQ+MySQL in the past but I like the option of Mnesia for messaging with persistance. Also, is it alright to use AMQP 0.9 instead of 1.0. Looks like RabbitMQ support 1.0 via a plugin.

Appreciate any alternate suggestions I can get.

Comment: We picked RabbitMQ and used it to transfer low frequency loads of data with federation. We tried scaling RabbitMQ for 2K messages/sec (no federation needed) and Kafka proved to be much better.